# Is there a way to use endswith/startswith in match case statements?

Tags: python, match, case

Is there a way to use match case to select string endings/beginnings like below?

```
match text_string:
  case 'bla-bla':
    return 'bla'
  case .endswith('endofstring'):
    return 'ends'
  case .startswith('somestart'):
    return 'start'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You were close. You wanted a conditional **guard** on a pattern that otherwise matches anything.

```
match text_string:
  case 'bla-bla':
    return 'bla'
  case s if s.endswith('endofstring'):
    return 'ends'
  case s if s.startswith('somestart'):
    return 'start'
```

This doesn't gain much over the following.

```
if text_string == 'bla-bla':
  return 'bla'
elif text_string.endswith('endofstring'):
  return 'ends'
elif text_string.startswith('somestart'):
  return 'start'
```

*Unless* you're also using the `match` and want to differentiate between two otherwise identical patterns.

Comment: This was is just an oversimplified  example. I have a match case with about 20 cases some with multiple values. So it would help a lot to clarify and maintain code, especially when i have multiple endings for one particular case. Thanks